# Probability of drawing a red ball if I draw 11 balls from an urn of 25 balls with 5 being red balls.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Imagine you have an urn with $25$ balls in it. $20$ of the balls are black and $5$ of the balls are red. If I draw $11$ balls from the urn, what is the probability that none of them are red? I have written python code to test it, and empirically I believe it should be $\sim 1.85\text{%}$.

I had a naive idea to compute it as,

$$1 - \left((20/25)*(19/24)*...*(10/15)\right) \approx 0.024$$

I thought, the probability of getting a black ball on the first try is $20/25$, the probability of getting a black ball on the second, given I got one on the first, is $19/24$, and so on.

Comment: Are you replacing the balls as you draw them, or not?  Either way, it should be a routine computation...

Comment: no replacement.

Comment: So, what goes wrong with the usual method?  Just count the ways to do it with no red balls and divide by the unrestricted total.

Comment: Can you just tell me why it's wrong and post the answer, a friend and I are arguing. It's not for school.

Comment: The answer is just $\binom {20}{11}\big / \binom {25}{11}\approx 0.03768$ ... not sure where your number comes from.

Comment: The exact answer is (no numerical count...) $$\frac{\binom{20}{11}}{\binom{25}{11}}\ .$$ This is in sage (well, if you know python...) `binomial(20, 11) / binomial(25, 11)` and this is $13/345\approx 0.037681159420289\dots$

Comment: Can you explain why my naive computation was wrong?

Comment: Ask a clear question, please, from the beginning. Why do you insert that "one minus"?

Comment: Because the probability after the $1-$ is the probability that I DON'T get a red ball.

Comment: The probability after "one minus" is the probability to extract $11$ black balls from $20$ black plus $5$ red without replacement, this is the probability you need. Then just tell us how this is so small. And all the numbers differ, $1.85$ per cent is then not $.024$.  To have a clear situation, if there is only one ball extracted (instead of eleven), which is the probability? For two balls? For three?!

Comment: I suppose that $\frac{19}{14}$ is a typo for $\frac{19}{24}$?

Comment: Had you just computed $\frac {20}{25}\times \frac {19}{24}\times \cdots \times \frac {10}{15}$ you'd have been ok.  That's $.037681159$, same as the other method.  I still have no idea where your numbers are coming from.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is error (probably a typo) in ''$\left((20/25)*(19/14)*...*(10/15)\right)$''. Secondly you shouldn't have subtracted it from $1$.

The probability changes from one draw to the next when balls are drawn one by one without replacement.

Number of different ways of selecting $11$ balls out of $25$ balls so that none of drawn balls is red  $$\frac{20}{25}\cdot \frac{19}{24} \cdot \frac{18}{23}\cdot \ldots \frac{11}{16}\cdot\frac{10}{15}=\frac{13}{345}$$

Comment: Can you tell me what's wrong with my naive computation, I have edited my answer.

Comment: How did get that formula for computation. You need to explain more about your method. Is there no replacement.? However I have given you straight forward method

Answer (score 0):

I'll break down what you did wrong:

You want to find the probability that all $11$ balls selected are black (not red).

And you're using the complement method which states that the probability (Event A happening) = $1$ - probability (Event A not happening)

e.g. Prob (getting a $2$ after rolling a dice) = $\frac{1}{6}$ or another way to calculate this is to first find the Prob (not getting a $2$ after rolling a dice) = $\frac{5}{6}$ and then subtracting this from $1$. So Prob (getting a $2$ after rolling a dice) = $1- \frac{5}{6} = \frac{1}{6}$ again.

In your case Event A = All $11$ balls are black.

What you have done is first calculated the Prob(A) = Prob (All $11$ balls are black) = $\frac{20}{25} \times \frac{19}{24}\times...\times \frac{10}{15}$ and you should have just left it here. This was the correct answer.

But instead you took this answer and subtracted it from $1$ which now gives you the Prob (all $11$ balls are not black). Hope this clears it out!